# Changing the תפילת בית המדרש

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, talmud-bavli, tractate-brachot, acharonim

The גמרא in מסכת ברכות on  [דף כח עמוד ב](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Berachoth&df=28b)  gives a תפילה for people to say when entering a בית המדרש. This is quoted  [להלכה in רמב''ם ברכות י,כג](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=36436&rid=1098)   and [שולחן ערוך אורח חיים קי,ח](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x479). However, the ט''ז on that piece of שולחן ערוך writes that he has a נוסח that he thinks people should say instead. (This נוסח can be found there and all of the above can be found on the inside cover of any עוז והדר gemara.)

How can the ט''ז do this? The גמרא has given a נוסח. It was decided by תנאים/אמוראים. How can an אחרון suggest he has something to replace it?
I am not asking because of משנה מטבע שטבעו חכמים. The question is how he can think his נוסח is better.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think the Tannaim's version is better for us to say? For example, Tannaim prayed for the welfare of Sumer or something not the US [or insert country here], but for us the latter is more appropriate.

Comment: @Double AA I thought that was self evident, this is the same form of תורה learning as back then, not at all comparable to country changing

Comment: Doesn't the Taz say he's giving this alternate text for a different case of one who sits to learn by himself, instead of the Gemara's case of entering the study hall to learn?

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree. That is what I answered +/-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taz explains itself:

Some parts are added for situations in which one study alone, and some part for Dayan giving a psak alone. He also added special tefila linked to the difficulty of the isolated student, nobody to help it for errors correction. In almost each of the brachot of amida we can add something, bakasha, "chidush" following the words of Gemara. It is not considered as "משנה ממטבע שטבעו חכמים".

> והוא הדין במי שישב ללמוד אפילו ביחידות, ובפרט במי שהגיע להוראה. ‏
>
> Similarly there is a need of prayer for who learn alone and who go to show people how to do.
>
> ובהקשר ליחידות הט"ז מוסיף: "יהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלקי ואלקי אבותיי שתאיר עיניי במאור תורתך " ‏
>
> prayer for an illumination directly from H' because there are no friend or Rabbi.
>
> בגלל שאין מי שיתקו אותו כשהוא לומד לבד הוסיף: "ומה ששגיתי כבר העמידני על האמת ואל תצל מפי דבר אמת עד מאוד" ‏
>
> prayer for self correcting.
>
> ובקשר להוראה הוא מוסיף: "ותצילני מידי כל מכשול וטעות הן בדיני איסור והיתר הן בדיני ממונות הן בהוראה" ‏
>
> prayer for right psak.

Comment: The ט''ז doesn't say that he is fixing anything in the original נוסח. The original נוסח was for a 'נכנס לבית המדרש', independent of him having a friend to learn with. He just says 'this is a great short נוסח including lots'. I have now edited the question to show that I am not bothered by מטבע שטבעו חכמים, the question is why he thinks he is better than חז''ל. Also, your comparison to adding in תפילה isn't great, because that is adding, this is changing.

Comment: @MosheSteinberg See please the first statement quoted, I understand that it is not a formal proof but he added Byichidut and Horaa. horaa is congruent to his second addition, and Yichidut to the first. If you read against the Mishna, אמרו לו מה מקום לתפילה זו אמר להם בכניסתי אני מתפלל שלא תארע תקלה על ידי. you can understand the explanation of the nusach quoted Bagemara. Takala == a Bein Adam Lachavero problem. This is not relevant at all if you learn alone in your room. You may argue that Taz added Tefilot in situations that Rabbi Nechunia does not mentioned.

Comment: it isn't clear that the ט''ז is doing what you say he is doing but it is possible so I accept the answer